# Class Property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, prototype

I have a question about class properties. I'll create an example for better understanding. Let's say we have a class.

```
   class Person {}
```

And we want to add a property. How do we do that? From what I read there are 2 ways:

```
  class Person {myProperty ='Something'} //As shown at https://javascript.info/class. If we use console.log(Person) the property will not show
```

Now let's create another class that extends Person, let's say Athlete and I want to change myProperty:

```
  class Athlete extends Person{// If we use console.log(Athlete.myProperty ) it will show undefined
       myProperty='Something else'// it changes the property

        writeSomething() {
            console.log(this.myProperty);
        }
   }
```

Now let's create a new object using Athlete as constructor

```
const athlete = new Athlete();
console.log(athlete)// It will have the property myProperty with value 'Something else'
```

My questions are:

1. Where is myProperty stored, I can't find it anywhere inside Person or Athlete?
2. Why can I access myProperty inside writeSomething()?
3. Why does myProperty appear inside athlete, when it didn't appear anywhere else?
4. Is this another way of writing properties as opposed to Person.myProperty  or is it something else?

Thank you,

Elanvi

Comment: Sorry about this, instead of 'And we want to add a property. How do we do that? From what I read there are 2 ways:' consider 'And we want to add a property'. I wanted to compare this method with Person.myProperty in paralel but it got way to confusing so I simplified it and forgot to change.

Comment: Have a look at static properties here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields

Comment: Hi yes, you can define a new instance variable using a syntax similar to how you defined `myProperty`.

Comment: Questions that encompass multiple questions are not a good fit for stack overflow. They are not likely to help others. Please create a more focused question. This look probably answers your questions

Comment: Thank you for your answers guys, I get it now. What I was asking about was basically Public instance fields, but I didn't know the term. As you mentioned documentation can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields.

Comment: Was confused by the fact that on https://javascript.info/class it reffered to it as a class property, same in a course on udemy that I'm taking

Answer (score 3):

First of all, they are not "class properties". They are instance properties just declared upfront. This gives you the clear idea about what fields (properties) can be expected ***from the class instance***.

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

> Public and private field declarations are an [experimental feature (stage 3)](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) proposed at TC39, the JavaScript standards committee.
>   Support in browsers is limited, but the feature can be used through a
>   build step with systems like Babel.

So, based on the proposal in the link, your code is for declaring *public* properties of the class instances:

```
class Person {
  myProperty ='Something' // this means anyone can access the property
}
```

For *private* properties, they're suggesting this syntax:

```
class Person {
  #myPrivateProperty ='Something' // this means only the instance methods have access
}
```

To answer your questions:

> 1. Where is myProperty stored, I can't find it anywhere inside Person or Athlete?

It's stored as an instance property of an instance of the `Person` class. Since `Athlete` extends it, an instance of `Athlete` also will be given the same property. Read [Object Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) for more details.

> 2. Why can I access myProperty inside writeSomething()?

`writeSomething()` is the method of the instance, so it has access to any instance property. (public *and* private)

> 3. Why does myProperty appear inside athlete, when it didn't appear anywhere else?

It should appear in a `Person` instance as well. For example, you can write:

```
const person = new Person();
person.myProperty = 'new Something';
```

> 4. Is this another way of writing properties as opposed to Person.myProperty or is it something else?

It's just a declaration of instance properties made easier and more intuitive, and with implied access modifier (i.e. `public`).

---

Finally, if you want to **declare a class property**, you need to specify it as a `static` property like this:

```js
class Person {
  static myProperty = 'some value';
}
console.log(Person.myProperty);
```

Comment: Isn't the OP asking for a static property? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

Comment: I don't believe so. he's asking 4 questions based on the code he posted. there's no mention of static property specifically.

Comment: @JuanMendes updated my answer to address static property part as well.

Comment: They asked: `@// If we use console.log(Athlete.myProperty` that looks like they expected the property to be on the constructor

Comment: But yes, it's a poorly asked question, there should be only one question per post

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer your questions as best I can:

> 1. Where is myProperty stored, I can't find it anywhere inside Person or Athlete?

Writing:

```
class Person { myProperty = 'Something' }
```

Is the same as writing:

```
class Person {
  constructor() {
    this.myProperty = 'Something';
  }
}
```

My understanding is that writing it the first way actually adds the property definition to the constructor - you won't see `myProperty` anywhere on the prototype of `Person`, the property will not exist anywhere until an instance is created with `new Person` and the constructor is called.

> 2. Why can I access myProperty inside writeSomething()?

You can access `myProperty` inside `writeSomething` through the `this` context as it will refer to the instance of `Person` unless otherwise bound.

> 3. Why does myProperty appear inside athlete, when it didn't appear anywhere else?

The property isn't inside of `Athlete` per-se but without defining it's own constructor it will inherit the parent class constructor meaning `Athlete` instances will get the same property defined when they are instantiated. If you were to add a constructor to `Athlete` you would have to call the `super` constructor (i.e. `Person` constructor) at which time the property would be defined on the intstance.

> 4. Is this another way of writing properties as opposed to Person.myProperty or is it something else?

As described above, you can also define these instance properties in the constructor with `this.myProp = 'my value'`. You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields) on how to use class fields.

Answer (score 0):

> Where is myProperty stored, I can't find it anywhere inside Person or
>   Athlete?

[Public instance fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields) on classes are syntactic sugar for instantiating instance [own properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) from inside the class constructor.

```
class Person { constructor() { this.p1 = 'p1 value' } }
```

Given the following:

```
class Person { p1 = 'p1 value'; p2 = 'p2 value' }

class Athlete extends Person { p1 = 'p1 overridden value' }
```

The `prototype` property of the `Person` class is placed on to the prototype chain of the `prototype` property of the `Athlete` class.

```
console.log(Athlete.prototype.__proto__ === Person.prototype) // true
```

The `prototype` property of the `Person` class does not contain the `p1` property, because it will be dynamically added by the default constructor of the `Person` class, when an instance is created.

```
console.log(Person.prototype.hasOwnProperty('p1')) // false

const p = new Person()
```

When newing-up a `Person` the constructor dynamically adds the property to the resulting instance.

```
console.log(p.hasOwnProperty('p1')) // true

const a = new Athlete()
```

When newing-up an `Athlete` the `Person` super constructor is implicitly called against the `Athlete` instance putting both `p1` and `p2` on the instance, finally the `Athlete` constructor is run and `p1` is overwritten.

```
console.log(a.hasOwnProperty('p1')) // true
console.log(a.hasOwnProperty('p2')) // true
console.log(a.p1) // p1 value overridden
```

> Why can I access myProperty inside writeSomething()?

This is just normal `this` behavior. When invoking a function as a method, the target of the method is the object it was invoked upon. In this case, the instance of `Athlete`.

Answer (score -1):

> 1) Where is myProperty stored, I can't find it anywhere inside Person or Athlete?

Variables that can be accessed inside `Person` or `Athlete` are called `static` class variables. You can define them by either doing:

```
Person.staticProperty = 'Something';
```

or

```
class Person {
  static staticProperty = 'Something';
}
```

This variable can be accessed inside your class:

```
class Person {
   static staticProperty = 'Something';

  logStaticProperty() {
    console.log(Person.staticProperty);
  }
}
```

> 2) Why can I access myProperty inside writeSomething()?

When you create an instance of a class using `new`, you can attach variables that are isolated to that single instance. The syntax being used in the constructor attaches the variable to the instance.

> 3) Why does myProperty appear inside athlete, when it didn't appear anywhere else?

See #2.

> 4) Is this another way of writing properties as opposed to Person.myProperty or is it something else?

Using the `constructor` method is functionally equivalent

```
class Person {
  constructor() {
    this.myProperty = 'Somethin';
  }
}
```